# Storing data from API in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm new to Realm. Right now I have a simple app that pulls news articles from an api. The first view controller shows a list of the article titles, the second view controller shows the article selected from the `tableView` in a `webView`.

I'd like to use Realm to store the data from the API, so the `tableView` will show results even if there is no internet Connection.

I see the tutorials that use `Mantle`, but I'm trying to do it without that.

This is what I've tried so far, but my use of `valueForKey` crashed the app, so I commented it out.

```
- (void)startParsing
{
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss#sthash.TyhRD7Zy.dpuf"]];
    [xmlparser setDelegate:self];
    [xmlparser parse];
    if (_marrXMLDataCollection.count != 0) {

        Data *dataRealm = [[Data alloc] init];
        dataRealm.titleR = @"Temporary title";
//        dataRealm.titleR = [_marrXMLDataCollection valueForKey:@"title"];

        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
        [realm beginWriteTransaction];
        [realm addObject:dataRealm];
        [realm commitWriteTransaction];

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be great, thanks!

*Here's more info if needed:*

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"rss"]) {
        _marrXMLDataCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        _mdictXMLPartCollection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
{
    if (!_mstrXMLStringCollection) {
        _mstrXMLStringCollection = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    }
    else {
        [_mstrXMLStringCollection appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]
        || [elementName isEqualToString:@"link"]

        ) {
        [_mdictXMLPartCollection setObject:_mstrXMLStringCollection forKey:elementName];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [_marrXMLDataCollection addObject:_mdictXMLPartCollection];
    }
    _mstrXMLStringCollection = nil;
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Randy is this possible without using Mantle, or is it too hard to do without Mantle, and everything that follows from there basically. Thanks!

Comment: @Randy or if what I'm doing even makes sense to need Realm for?

Comment: I don't know `Mantle` actually, but it is not needed for what you want to achieve. Your can use `Realm` for that, it's a good idea.  Now, what is your problem actually? Your code looks good a priori. You parse the XML files your receive from your server and then you create `Realm` objects with the necessary information. It doesn't work ?

Comment: @Randy in the case of no internet connection, I need to still load the table view even if it is with old data headlines from the last time there was an internet connection when loaded. So I'm at the point where I'm trying to figure out how to get the objects out of Realm, and then also thinking to myself is there an easier/better way to do this than with Realm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what you saw was [this article on the Realm website](https://realm.io/news/tutorial-mantle-realm/) about integrating Realm and Mantle.

It's absolutely not necessary to use Realm with any third party parsing libraries. The point of Mantle in that article was to make it easier to convert a JSON response from a REST API into a model object (including things like date strings to `NSDate` in the process) that could then be handed over to a Realm object.

Your Realm code looks correct here (Assuming that `Date` has properly been made a subclass of `RLMObject`), so it would appear there is something wrong with your XML parsing code. `NSXMLParser` is a rather tricky class to work with since it requires you to build your XML data graph sequentially through delegate callbacks.

For the purpose of parsing XML that's being served from an API (i.e., it would inherently be small, discrete blocks. `NSXMLParser` is designed for ridiculously huge XML data sets.), I would instead recommend using another XML library that goes through and processes the entire XML set before handing to to you. I've used [TBXML](https://github.com/71squared/TBXML) in shipping apps before, and there's [a Ray Wenderlich article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) that discusses more of them (Granted, it's pretty out-of-date at this point).

If anyone else knows of any more recent XML libraries that are recommended, please chime in. :)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for talking me thru a few different options on this-